# Cakephp Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, datetime, timezone, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.3 .. here is my code

```
  class MessagesController extends AppController{
     public $helpers = array('Time');

    public function messages(){

    $datetime=  $this->Message->getDatetime($userid); //$datetime = 2013-06-14 10:28:00



    $time = $this->Userinfo->getTimeZone($userid);   //$time = 5.00

   $finaltime =   $this->Time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTime, NULL, $time);
```

exit();

```
}
```

it is giving me

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that just because you are using the $helper in the controller doesn't mean it is accessible. It is actually geting passed to the view or .ctp file.

```
// called as CakeTime
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
echo CakeTime::format('2011-08-22', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::format

Comment: this problem has been solved before but for a different version of cakephp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779176/cakephp-time-helper-problem

Comment: Class 'TimeHelper' not found  is coming

Comment: are you making something that is dependent on different timezones? otherwise you can specificy it in the config.php file

Comment: well thankyou for your help ... well i come up to a solution from the link you gave me in which someone mention that helpers are designed to access them in a view page so now i am using helper in a view ...so now i am converting time on view page instead of controller

Comment: yes that would make more sense, pass all your data to the view then output